# App Localization in iOS4

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, localization, ios4

I recall hearing that with the introduction of iOS 4.0, you no longer need to use the `NSLocalizedString` macro in order to localize strings within an application into different languages. However, I have been unable to find any information or documentation about the new method that can be used for localization. Am I dreaming, or have I missed something obvious? If there is a new method for localization, I would much appreciate it if someone could point me in the direction of some resources on the topic. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking through the documentation, I can't find any mention of a new method of localization.